# WSL2 Ubuntu cannot ping local ip

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

I need to find out why I'm not able to ping my local IP for my main computer from my ubuntu wsl terminal. For some reason, the WSL ip is 172.24.61.1/20. I have a postgresql server on 192.168.1.247 my main pc but it cannot even ping it. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Firewall!

Turn off the firewall in windows and check the ping. Once it starts pinging add a rule for incoming and outgoing.

To turn off firewall in linux just use

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

that is if you have firewall installed there, check it by using

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

Comment: nps, now its a bad idea to keep it off, go ahead and add a rule for the same in the firewall(windows) to accept incoming requests for ping:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-icmp-rule

Comment: Well I'm going to need to allow access not just for ping though. I also need to allow access to my postgre firewall.

Comment: I have the same problem. Windows firewall is disabled yet I cannot ping the windows host (external IP) or the IP address of the vEthernet (WSL) adapter from wsl2.

Comment: You need to set some context for us here, what is the config and is the ping not working from either of the hosts A to B and B to A??